# A quick search of the average variable list

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, average

I have a list that is constantly added value, and every time I need to count the arithmetic mean. Is there any way to do it faster than simply memorizing the sum of the elements and divide by the size of the list?

Comment: It will not get faster than an addition and increment and a divide. That is already **O(1)**.

Comment: you can also memorize the size of the list, and just add 1 for every new item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't get faster than a single updating calculation after incrementing the number of values, that is

[image: add]

This is evidently constant `O(1)` time complexity.

A corresponding approach to update the average of a sample after removing a value would simply be

[image: remove]